# Create a list of maps from multiple lists

Tags: groovy

Given three lists:

```
l1 = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Jane']
l2 = ['30', '40', '50']
l3 = ['NY', 'Berlin', 'Stockholm']
```

how do I create something like this:

```
[['name': 'Alice', 'age': '30', 'city': 'NY'],
 ['name': 'Bob', 'age': '40', 'city': 'Berlin'],
 ['name': 'Jane', 'age': '50', 'city': 'Stockholm']]
```

I've tried `[l1,l2,l3].transpose()` but it returns list of lists and I can't figure out how to add proper keys to `collectEntries()`

Thanks

**Edit:**
Not-so-elegant solution I came up with is this:

```
assert l1.length == l2.length
assert l2.length == l3.length

def mapping = []
l1.eachWithIndex {name, index -> 
def obj = [:]
obj.name = name
obj.age = l2[index]
obj.city = l3[index]
mapping += obj
obj = []
};
```

But there must be a better way, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt at solving this more elegantly.

The following code:

```
def l1 = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Jane']
def l2 = ['30', '40', '50']
def l3 = ['NY', 'Berlin', 'Stockholm']

def result = [l1, l2, l3].transpose().collect { a, b, c -> 
  [name: a, age: b, city: c]
}

println result
```

when run, prints out:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy 
[[name:Alice, age:30, city:NY], 
 [name:Bob,   age:40, city:Berlin], 
 [name:Jane,  age:50, city:Stockholm]]

~>
```

(formatting added for readability).

The trick here is the [transpose method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#transpose()) which the question already mentions - `[l1, l2, l3].transpose()` returns:

```
[[Alice, 30, NY], [Bob, 40, Berlin], [Jane, 50, Stockholm]]
```

and the `collect { a, b, c ->` expression uses groovy destructuring to assign `[Alice, 30, NY]` to `a, b, c` etc. This is essentially the same mechanics that make it possible to write:

```
def (a, b, c) = [1, 2, 3]
```

for multiple assignments.

`collectEntries` returns a map and since you want a list on the outermost level it's not really the right tool here.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for